# Change the default install location of macports

Tags: macports

Is it possible to change the default install location of packages installed from macports?

I am trying to install numpy/scipy module. But it goes to /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/... instead of /System/Library/Frameworks/...

Or it's not a good idea in the first place?

Comment: this question is not strictly related to python and numpy: tags removed

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts aims to be self-contained and thus doesn't touch any system-installed stuff (not even by installing python modules). Use MacPorts python if you want to use the python modules installed using MacPorts.

It is not possible (without a *lot* of effort) to change this behavior.